# Discord.js interaction calculate latency

Tags: discord.js

I just started building a Discord bot and I'm trying to get a client-side *API latency* from the moment when client use the bot's command until they receive a response. In other words, from client to server and server to client. Is that possible?

```
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('bored')
        .setDescription('Send a random things to do'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const url = 'http://www.example.com';

        let response;
        try {
            response = await axios.get(url);
            console.log(response.data);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        const embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setDescription(response.data.activity)

        await interaction.reply({embeds: [embed]});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the API latency you can use:

```
const ping = client.ws.ping;
```

To get the Bot latency you need to calculate the difference in time between the timestamp of the interaction and the current time.

```
const botLatency = Date.now() - interaction.createdTimestamp;
```